How should I choose what happens to my protagonist?
The main plot of my story is that a girl named Arabella signs up for a dance competition and practices for weeks. Fearing that the other dancers are too good, she invites them over to a practice session at her house. She takes note of their strengths and weaknesses. Soon she goes to the dance competition and realizes that she isn't going to win. She goes out anyway but fails on her back tuck. She gets a concussion and blacks out.
That is all I have so far, and I can't figure out what should happen next: whether the concussion has any long term side effects or if she should quit dancing. I am having a really hard time figuring out what Arabella does about this concussion.
What do I do?

We cannot tell you how your story should continue, but you can consider:

What do you want the narrative arc for your protagonist to be? What development do you want her to undergo? What do you want her to learn?
What kind of story do you want it to be? What is your theme? What message do you want to give to your readers?
What kind of person are you? What kind of ending do you like to read?

Take a walk and brainstorm these and similar questions. That should give you a couple of possible directions. Choose the one that resonates the most with you.

It might also be that with the concussion you have written yourself into a corner. Take your story up until the beginning of the competition and then consider the ideas you had during the brainstorming described above. What continuation seems most natural and most fitting? Maybe you want something else to happen rather than a concussion?

Example
Your story seems to be about a person with pronounced performance orientation (that is, a person getting self-worth from achievement instead of, e.g., having satisfying friendships or contributing to the community) and what that person's competitiveness, fear of failure, and envy lead them to.
If performance orientation is an ideal that you share, you might want to show how your protagonist doesn't give up and keeps on working hard for her goals despite her setback. If you have other ideals, your protagonist's competitors might stop the competition and help her. They have seen her as a friend and act accordingly, while she has seen them as competitors. Through their compassion she learns that she has worth despite her failure and finnaly finds friendships. Her future training is more cooperative and supportive of each other.
That are two direcitons your story might take. Now, don't simply write my ideas, but do your own brainstorming and come up with the story that you want to narrate!

What does your decision-making process look like? I can list many potential ways a story could go, but I'm hardly ever satisfied with any of them. Even if, intellectually, it sounds like a good decision, I often can't scrounge the motivation to write it, and sometimes I'm half-way into planning a project when I realize I don't quite understand what I want to write; I've a general feel for it, but I can't pin it down into something specific.

@verified_tinker As I suggested in my answer: (a) What is the theme of your story and what are your personal values? When a beginning is given, the interaction between your theme and your values (that is, your personal opinion about a theme) usually indicates a certain desirable outcome. (b) What lesson do you want your protagonist to learn? What do you want to teach your readers? (c) What kind of story do you like to read? — All of these together usually "force" my stories into a very specific direction. The prerequisite is to know yourself. Then it's less a decision and rather a realization.
